# Mongodb aggregate $match inconsistent handling of dates between mongo and javascript

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm doing the following aggregation in the mongodb shell:

```
db.sensors.aggregate([
    { $match: { timestamp: {$gte: ISODate("2016-08-08T15:46:00.0Z")} } },
    { $group: { 
        _id: "$sensorId", 
        avgSensor: { $avg: "$value" }, 
        avgDuration: { $avg: "$duration"} 
    }} 
])
```

which works fine and gives me an aggregate of documents with a timestamp later than 15:46.

If I do the equivalent thing in Node.js :

```
sensors.aggregate([
    { $match: { timestamp: { $gte: new Date('2016-08-08T15:46.000Z') } } },
    { $group: { 
        _id: "$sensorId", 
        avgSensor: { $avg: "$value" }, 
        avgDuration: { $avg: "$duration"} 
    }} 
], function (err,aggregate) { ...error handling stuff }
```

then I get a different (wrong) set of data that seems to ignore the date and match on everything.

So I think that `ISODate()` and `Date()` are not directly comparable.  Any idea how I solve this so my javascript works?

---

This may be a clue: if I try doing a date range in mongodb it works fine, but a date range in javascript returns no match:

```
sensors.aggregate([
    { $match: { timestamp: { 
        $gte: new Date('2016-08-08T15:46.000Z'), 
        $lt: new Date('2016-08-09T09:00.00Z') 
    } } }, 
    { $group: { 
        _id: "$sensorId", 
        avgSensor: { $avg: "$value" }, 
        avgDuration: { $avg: "$duration"} 
    }} 
], function (err,aggregate) { ...error handling... }
```

Comment: Have you tried with the other `Date` constructor `new Date(2016,7,8,15,46,0)`?

Comment: `new Date('2016-08-08T15:46.000Z')` returns `undefined`; the Node.js `Date` can't parse ISO dates.

Comment: Thanks to @chridam for the answer.   It seems that any efforts to use the ISODate format don't work .

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks to @chridam for the answer.  The corrected code (complete with working date range) is:

```
var daystart=new Date(2016,07,08,16,46,0);
var daystop=new Date(2016,07,08,17,46,0);
sensors.aggregate([{$match: { timestamp: { $gte: daystart, $lt: daystop } } }, {$group: { _id: "$sensorId", avgSensor: { $avg: "$value" }, avgDuration: { $avg: "$duration"} }} ], function (err,aggregate) {
```

... error handling... }

It seems that trying to use ISODate in Javascript was the problem.  Note that the Date constructor used is a bit weird with months - I had to use 07 for August.

Comment: When using the JavaScript [**`Date()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) constructor, the month parameter is `0-`index based i.e. January is 0, Feb is 1 etc